# Error in sound recording

Tags: java, android, audio, record

I'm a new developer.
I want to record a sound by holding a button and i want to play it with mediaplayer class.

i have a folder in my sdcard and all of the sounds I've recorded are saved in it.
when i click on play button, the last saved sound file or modified sound is played.

Error1: when i click on nextbtn my app gets force closed.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException
>               at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
>               at com.example.mehrdad.calendar.Event$4.onClick(Event.java:201)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4103)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17117)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Error2:when i release recordbtn my stop function is not called.

this is my code in oncreate methode

```
             File adr = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myFolder" + "/" + mDate[2] + "-" + mDate[1] + "-" + mDate[0]+"/voice");
        File[] files = adr.listFiles();
        if (!(files == null || files.length == 0)) {
            File lastModifiedFile = files[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                playlist.add(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
                if (lastModifiedFile.lastModified() < files[i].lastModified()) {
                   currentTrack=i;
                    myfile=Uri.parse(playlist.get(currentTrack));
                }
            }
              mp = MediaPlayer.create(Event.this,myfile);
            i=1;

        }

        btnPlay= (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(i==1) {
                    try {
                        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                           mp.pause();
                        }
                        mp.start();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if(i==0)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No sound to play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    });
        btnNextVoice= (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextVoice);
        btnNextVoice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                }
                currentTrack=(currentTrack+1)%playlist.size();
                myfile=Uri.parse(playlist.get(currentTrack));
                mp=MediaPlayer.create(Event.this,myfile);
                try {
                    mp.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                mp.start();
            }
        });
        btnLastVoice= (Button) findViewById(R.id.lastVoice);
        btnLastVoice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                }
                currentTrack=(currentTrack-1)%playlist.size();
                myfile=Uri.parse(playlist.get(currentTrack));
                try {
                    mp.setDataSource(Event.this,myfile);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    mp.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mp.start();
            }
        });
btnStart.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final Date date = new Date();
                final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH-mm-ss");
                final File dir;
                Boolean canWrite = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().canWrite();
                if (canWrite) {
                    dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myFolder" + "/" + mDate[2] + "-" + mDate[1] + "-" + mDate[0]);
                } else {
                    dir = new File(Environment.getRootDirectory() + "/myFolder" + "/" + mDate[2] + "-" + mDate[1] + "-" + mDate[0]);
                }
                dir.mkdirs();
                myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                myRecorder.setOutputFile(String.valueOf(dir) + "/" + dateFormat.format(date) + ".amr");
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
                        start();
                        break;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{
                        stop();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

the stop() and start() function:

```
private void stop() {

        myRecorder.stop();
        myRecorder.reset();
        myRecorder.release();
        myRecorder = null;

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop recording...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


private void start() {


    try {
        myRecorder.prepare();
        myRecorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start recording...",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Is your `start()` function called from `onTouch()`, or is that `OnTouchListener` never used?

Comment: btnStart.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
                        start();
                        break;
                    }

i called it in onTouch(),when motion event is down

Comment: @KompjoeFriek

i called it in onTouch() in the btnStart.setOntouchListener

Comment: Yes i see, but can you verify it actually gets called when you press the button? I ask, because that would narrow down the places to look for your problem. I don't see btnStart getting initialized.

Comment: @KompjoeFriek
no no
all of the button initialized.
stop function called,and when myRecorder.stop() called i get error java.lang.IllegalStateException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1:

You are calling `prepare()` on a MediaPlayer that has already been prepared. Please see the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) for further details.

Problem 2:

You create a new MediaRecorder before you call `start()`, but also before you call `stop()`. You should move this block of code out of `onTouch()` into `start()`:

```java
            final Date date = new Date();
            final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH-mm-ss");
            final File dir;
            Boolean canWrite = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().canWrite();
            if (canWrite) {
                dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myFolder" + "/" + mDate[2] + "-" + mDate[1] + "-" + mDate[0]);
            } else {
                dir = new File(Environment.getRootDirectory() + "/myFolder" + "/" + mDate[2] + "-" + mDate[1] + "-" + mDate[0]);
            }
            dir.mkdirs();
            myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
            myRecorder.setOutputFile(String.valueOf(dir) + "/" + dateFormat.format(date) + ".amr");
```

Comment: is that your mean i have to move that block of code into start() function before i call myRecorder.start();?

Comment: Yes, that is what i mean. A new `MediaRecorder`  would be created when you want to start recording, and not when you want to stop recording. This would leave `myRecorder` in a good state to call `myRecorder.stop()`. Please see the states of `MediaRecorder` in the documentation link mentioned above.

Comment: im so sorry
i moved that block of code into start()function but anything not changed
i get foce closed